# Sql Query to split the string into 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Below string in SQL needs to be split based on keywords cleared by and clearing for

```
Paper Industry cleared by SBI
Chemical Industry cleared by HDFC
SBI clearing for automobile Industry
ICICI clearing for textile industry
```

I need to split the above string based on on keywords cleared by and clearing for to get the output in 2 columns

```
Output 
Company Name             | Clearer
------------------------------------------
Paper Industry           | SBI
Chemical Industry        | HDFC
automobile Industry      | SBI
textile industry         | ICICI
```

to get 2 columns company name and clearer.

What is the best way to split this and fetch the table valued result in SQL.

SQL query will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch.  You just need messy code:

```
select t.*,
       (case when col like '% cleared by %'
             then left(col, charindex(' cleared by ', col))
             else stuff(col, 1, charindex(' clearing for ', col) + 13, '')
        end) as company_name,
       (case when col like '% cleared by %'
             then stuff(col, 1, charindex(' cleared by ', col) + 11, '')
             else left(col, charindex(' clearing for ', col))
        end) as clearer
from t;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/15041) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an alternative way to solve this

Comment: @VikasKunte SQL Server is fairly bad when it comes to regex matching, which is what you really want to use here.  The alternative would be to scrub your data outside of SQL Server, or not let it happen in the first place.

Comment: @VikasKunte . . . There are lots of alternatives.  None are really going to be simpler, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `subsring()` with `left()` function :

```
select 
       (case when company like '% cleared by %'
             then left(company, charindex(' cleared by ', company))
             else substring(company, charindex('clearing for ', company)+13, LEN(company))
        end) as [Company Name],
       (case when company like '% cleared by %'
             then substring(company, charindex('cleared by ', company)+11, LEN(company))
             else left(company, charindex(' clearing for ', company))
        end) as Clearer
from table t
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well.
Hope this is helpful :)

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN [Left] LIKE '%industry' 
        THEN [Left]
        ELSE [Right]
        END [Company Name]
    ,CASE
        WHEN [Left] NOT LIKE '%industry' 
        THEN [Left]
        ELSE [Right]
        END [Clearer]
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(' cleared by ', Col) > 0
            THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(Col, CHARINDEX(' cleared by ', Col))))
            WHEN CHARINDEX(' clearing for ', Col) > 0
            THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(Col, CHARINDEX(' clearing for ', Col))))
            END [Left]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(' cleared by ', Col) > 0
            THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Col, CHARINDEX(' cleared by ', Col)+LEN(' cleared by '), LEN(Col))))
            WHEN CHARINDEX(' clearing for ', Col) > 0
            THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Col, CHARINDEX(' clearing for ', Col)+LEN(' clearing for '), LEN(Col))))
            END [Right]
        FROM table_name
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using a little XML in concert with a Cross Apply

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (id int,[SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Paper Industry cleared by SBI')
,(2,'Chemical Industry cleared by HDFC')
,(3,'SBI clearing for automobile Industry')
,(4,'ICICI clearing for textile industry')


Select CompanyName = XMLData.value('x[1]/@name','varchar(max)')
      ,Clearer     = XMLData.value('x[1]/@code','varchar(max)')
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(xml,case when charindex('cleared by',SomeCol)>0 
                                    then '<x name="'+replace(SomeCol,' cleared by '  ,'" code="')+'"/>'
                                    else '<x code="'+replace(SomeCol,' clearing for ','" name="')+'"/>'
                                    end) )
             ) B(XMLData)
```

**Returns**

```
CompanyName         Clearer
Paper Industry      SBI
Chemical Industry   HDFC
automobile Industry SBI
textile industry    ICICI
```

> **EDIT - Just for Fun and if the source is One Multi-Line String**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) ='Paper Industry cleared by SBI
Chemical Industry cleared by HDFC
SBI clearing for automobile Industry
ICICI clearing for textile industry'


Select CompanyName = XMLData.value('x[1]/@name','varchar(max)')
      ,Clearer     = XMLData.value('x[1]/@code','varchar(max)')
 From (
        Select RetVal = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@S,char(13)+char(10),'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
      ) A
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(xml,case when charindex('cleared by',RetVal)>0 
                                    then '<x name="'+replace(RetVal,' cleared by '  ,'" code="')+'"/>'
                                    else '<x code="'+replace(RetVal,' clearing for ','" name="')+'"/>'
                                    end ) )
             ) B(XMLData)
```